# Android Studio Doesn't Run The Flutter Demo

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, throw

I had flutter working a few weeks ago, but once I tried to clone a git hub repo something happened where now my Android Studio wont run any flutter app at all. My flutter doctor reports 0 errors, but when I try to launch the flutter demo I only get these lines in the terminal window:
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1
After using flutter run -v I have what is outlined within the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHiGN.png).
Like I said I have been working on this for a while now and keep getting the same error. I even uninstalled and reinstalled everything Android Studio/Flutter related, but nothing works.
Flutter version 1.20.3
Android version 4.0
Android SDK version 30.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```